# trying to get form on the same level as a section of images

Tags: html

Ok, so I am really new to this, and I couldn't think of a way to put it my problem words to find out if the same thing has previously been asked because I have a very specific problem, so if I have violated any rules that I am unaware of please tell me but try not to be rude :)
Ok, so i am designing a website and am trying to make the menu section on level as my username and password inputs, I have tried just about every  bit of html that I know (mind you its not a lot) but I just cant seem to get it

```
<div id="layer9" style="background-color:#cfcfcf;height:60px;">
<a href="Home"><img src="home.jpg" /></a>
<a href="Forums"><img src="forums.jpg" /></a>
<a href="Videos.html"><img src="videos.jpg" /></a>
<div align="right">
<p>
<form action="action_page.php" method="POST" target="Sign in.html">
<input type="submit" value="Sign in">
Username : <input type="text" name="user"></br>
Password : <input type="password" name="Password"></p>
</div></p>
</form>
</div>
```

everything that i try just makes them go on different lines, or something to go all wonky, so if anyone could please provide me with a solution that would be lovley, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I did was clean up the code a little for you. But I think your answer may lie in the CSS file. Try applying an in-line Display to the id or the class of the items you want in the same line. There are several ways to do this, But I don't want to alter your source code too much. The , I changed to  on the CSS, create this this : 
I hope this helps.

```
 <div id="layer9" style="background-color:#cfcfcf;height:60px;">
     <a href="Home"><img src="home.jpg" /></a>
     <a href="Forums"><img src="forums.jpg" /></a>
     <a href="Videos.html"><img src="videos.jpg" /></a>
    <div style="float:right">
        <p>
            <form action="action_page.php" method="POST" target="Sign in.html">
                <input type="submit" value="Sign in">Username :
   `enter code here`             <input type="text" name="user">
                </br>Password :
                <input type="password" name="Password">
        </p>
    </div>
    </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

On the CSS try this:

```
 #layer9{ 
    display: inline;
    float: left;  
}
```